# how to get sum with table and minus with other table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

budget

```
id | project_name | total_budget
1  |    test      | 5000
2  |    try       | 200
```

expense

```
id|  project_name |paper|ballpen|total
1 | test          |100  |200    | 300
2 | test          |50   |50     |100
3 | try           |20   |0      |20
```

so the total of the test project_name is 400

```
5000 - 400 = 4600
```

try 200 -20 = 180
i want this one result

sorry im a newbie i cant get this one

Comment: What queries have you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple join with aggregation:

```
select b.project_name, b.total_budget, e.total as total_expense, b.total_budget - e.total as diff
from budget b left join
     (select project_name, sum(total) as total
      from expense e
      group by project_name
     ) e
     on b.project_name = e.project_name;
```

If you want this for one project_name, just add a `where` clause:

```
where b.project_name = 'test'
```